# Slow Down Spinning/Alternating Text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a rotating text effect like this: http://www.massstudies.com/. However, I would like the rotation speed to slow down when the user hover above the text. I currently have it as such that it stops, i'm using the clearInterval.

Any advice is deeply appreciated. Thanks:)

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

   <p id="text"></p>

   <button onclick="pauseRotation();">Stop</button>

</div>
```

Script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var words = ['Chocolate', 'Sugar','Cocoa Powder', 'Salt'];
    var index = 0;

    var nIntervId;

    function rotate() {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML =words[(index++)%(words.length)];
    }

    nIntervId=setInterval(rotate, 100);

    function pauseRotation(){
      clearInterval(nIntervId);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @bjb568 what do you mean? Like this, #text:hover{}; but what do i put in the curly braces?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, test it out in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ybyM/2/

```
var words = ['Chocolate', 'Sugar',"Cocoa Powder", 'Salt'];
var index = 0;

(function rotate() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML =words[(index++)%(words.length)];
  if($("#text").is(":hover")){
    setTimeout(rotate, 300);
  }
  else{
    setTimeout(rotate, 100);
  }
})()
```

Comment: hi:) thanks for the fiddle, but i've edited my code and now i'm using setInterval and clearInterval.

Comment: So you want the button to slow it down now? Or still a hover? Do you not want to use setTimeout even if it gives you the result you like? I updated it to your new html now, if that was what you were looking for?

Comment: i don't want the button. just the mouse hover. that is awesome. just a qn, would you not recommend the use of setInterval and clearInterval?